# WordPress category

Tags: categories

I want to get all categories in a new page which doesn't include any post. I tried wp_list_categories(); function. But it show only "No category" message. 
How do I do it?

Comment: There's an entire (wonderful!) site for these questions: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

This will only display the categories if there are posts associated with them, make sure that there are posts in your WordPress database. However, you might try:

```
wp_list_categories(array('hide_empty'=>0));
```

which will override that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<?php $categories = get_categories( $args ); ?> 

<?php 

$args = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 1,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
    'pad_counts'               => false 

); 

?>
```

also read about more details on this link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Answer (score 0):

This code will show and unordered list with the name of the category and the count  the total posts containing.

```
<ul class="myClass">
 <?php $categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty'=>0,'number=100'));
       foreach ($categories as $cat) {
       echo "<li>". $cat->cat_name . " - ". $cat->category_count ." posts.</li>";
       } ?>
</ul>
```

Retrieves the 100 first categories (*you can change the 100 for any number you want*)

```
$categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty'=>0,'number=100'));
```

and for each of them (**even the empty ones**) shows cat_name and category_count

Copy the code above in the page file you want to dispay the result.

You will get some like this:

- PHP - 0 posts.
- Uncategorized - 4 posts.
- WordPress - 1 posts.

I hope that could help you.

**ps:** *If you need them as links, replace the line*

```
 echo "<li>". $cat->cat_name . " - ". $cat->category_count ." posts.</li>";
```

*by*

```
echo '<li><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'">'. $cat->cat_name . '</a> - '. $cat->category_count .' posts.</li>';
```